# How to start Jenkins slave on docker-cloud?

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-machine

I have a jenkins master defined as a stack on cloud.docker.com. I also have set up a couple of other stacks that contain the services I need to test against during my build process (some components use mongo, some use rabbitmq, etc).

docker cloud (man I wish they picked a more unique name!) has a REST api to start stacks, and I've even written a script that will redeploy the stack based on UUID, but I can't figure out how to get the jenkins master to start the stack or how to execute my script.
The jenkins slave setup plugin didn't document how to attach the "setup" to a node, and none of the other plugins I looked at appeared to have support for neither docker cloud nor a way of using arbitrary rest apis on slave startup.

I've also tried just using the docker daemon to launch containers directly, but docker-cloud appears to remove images not associated with stacks or services on its managed node, and then the jenkins docker plugin complains it can't find the slave image. 
Everything is latest-and-greatest version-wise. The node itself is running on AWS and otherwise appears to function well.